# How can I list the current user's orders with Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I need a View which shows the list of all orders belong to the currently logged in user.

I looked at the Administrators Order View, there are some stuff with Commerce-Line Items but I couldnt figure out how they made that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new view showing "**Commerce order**" not "**Content**" as it is by default. Then add a contextual filter for "**Commerce Order: Uid**" and make it validate as the logged in user.

then you can add all the fields you want for that view

Answer (score 6):

There already is one provided with commerce_order_ui called commerce_user_orders. By default it's available at user/[uid]/orders. It needs the permission *View own orders of any type*.

Comment: I saw that indeed, I tried to manipulate that so that I could use it for authenticated users but i couldn't manage. Nevermind @Marius Ilie 's answer was satisfactory

Comment: @wallace740 Glad you've got it working. I'm not sure why you'd need to manipulate the view to get it working for authenticated users, for me it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I forgot to give Permission to Authenticated Users, that was the reason why Default Orders view not working in my occasion. **View own orders of any type**  this permission was disabled by me somehow. Thanks @Andy